# Cant get Edge to recognize encapsulated blob as a source url inside of a video element

Tags: angular, typescript, microsoft-edge

I need to use a blob as the source of a video file.

Everything works fine on Chrome and Safari but I am not able to get it to work on Edge

This method is built with typescript and I'm using Angular 7. What I see in Edge on mobile appears to be a broken link.

```
private initVideoFromBlob(blob: Blob) {
  const edBlob = new Blob([blob], { type: 'video/mp4' });
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(edBlob);
  this.videoSrc = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
}
```

I also tried this, but had the same result

```
private initVideoFromBlob(blob: Blob) {
  let url: any;
  const edBlob = new Blob([blob], { type: 'video/mp4' });
  if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    url = window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(edBlob);
  } else {
    url = (URL || webkitURL).createObjectURL(edBlob);
  }
  this.videoSrc = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
}
```

My Html:

```
<video controls>
  <source *ngIf="videoSrc" [src]="videoSrc" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

**Edit:**

I tried converting my blob to a dataURL as suggested by DarticCode but I am still getting the same result.

```
private async initVideoFromBlob(blob: Blob) {
  let url: string | boolean;
  const edBlob = new Blob([blob], { type: 'video/mp4' });
  if (/Edge\//.test(navigator.userAgent) || /EdgA\//.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const fr = new FileReader();
      fr.onload = x => resolve(fr.result);
      fr.readAsDataURL(edBlob);
    });

    url = await promise;
  } else {
    url = (URL || webkitURL).createObjectURL(edBlob);
  }
  this.videoSrc = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
}
```

Comment: Is there any 'open or save' popup in Edge when you using `window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob`? This method can trigger a 'open or save' popup and let you choose instead of displaying the file directly. Besides, is there any error in console on Edge?

Comment: No, that would be a good option if I could do that. Edge isn't displaying any errors in the console. The video file is even loading. It's all very odd.

Answer (score 2):

this is a bug which i will be fixed in a newer version your gonna have to convert the blob to a data uri

```js
//**dataURL to blob**
function dataURLtoBlob(dataurl) {
    var arr = dataurl.split(','), mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
        bstr = atob(arr[1]), n = bstr.length, u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
    while(n--){
        u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
    }
    return new Blob([u8arr], {type:mime});
}

//**blob to dataURL**
function blobToDataURL(blob, callback) {
    var a = new FileReader();
    a.onload = function(e) {callback(e.target.result);}
    a.readAsDataURL(blob);
}

//test:                    blob url \/
var blob = dataURLtoBlob('data:text/plain;base64,YWFhYWFhYQ==');
blobToDataURL(blob, function(dataurl){
    console.log(dataurl);
    
    //dataurl is a var here that gives it so what you wanna do with blob works with dataurl
});
```

Comment: I was hoping top avoid doing that because of how much bigger a data url is. Do you happen to have a link to this bug issue? I thought it might be a bug, but haven't been able to fine anything about it.

Comment: No sorry but i can give you the unification page about all of it on my site soon

Answer (score 0):

I made a test with a local video file and it seems that can work well on Edge. I don't have ready-made blob url, so I transfer the local video file to blob first. The code sample is like below, you could have a test:

```
<video controls>
    <source id="videoSrc" type="video/mp4" >
</video>

<script>
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';

    xhr.onload = function () {

        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = function () {

            var byteCharacters = atob(reader.result.slice(reader.result.indexOf(',') + 1));

            var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);

            for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {

                byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);

            }

            var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
            var blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'video/mp4' });
            var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

            document.getElementById('videoSrc').src = url;

        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);

    };

    xhr.open('GET', 'video/test.mp4');
    xhr.send();
</script>
```

The result is [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4zHX.jpg). If the issue still persists using the above function, you could try to make a minimal sample to reproduce the issue.